# Weird quadratic residue question.

Tags: number-theory

Show that is p is a prime s.t $ p \equiv 3 \mod 8 $ and $\frac{(p-1)}{2}$ is also prime then show that $\frac{(p-1)}{2}$ is a quadratic residue of p.

Now i am able to solve the problem except when $\frac{(p-1)}{2} \equiv 3$ i mean i believe that $\frac{(p-1)}{2} \equiv 1$ but i can't actually prove it.

Comment: In general $(\frac{ \frac{p-1}{2}}{p}) = (\frac{4 \frac{p-1}{2}}{p})= (\frac{-2}{p})=(\frac{-1}{p})(\frac{2}{p})$ which depends on $p \bmod 4$ and $p \bmod 8$.

Comment: the step with the 4 why do you know thats the case that u can multiply by 4?

Comment: It is [Legendre's symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol). For $p \ne 2$, $x^2 \equiv a \bmod p$ iff $(2x)^2 \equiv 4a \bmod p$, ie.  $(\frac{4a}{p}) =(\frac{a}{p})(\frac{4}{p}) =(\frac{a}{p})$.

Comment: Since $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is given to be a prime (say $q$), I suspect that this was given as a quadratic reciprocity problem. Since $p\equiv 1 \mod q$, $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = 1$; $q=\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv 1$ mod $4$, so $\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ is an odd prime, $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is a quadratic residue iff $-2$ is a quadratic residue.
Let us assume $p\equiv 3\pmod{8}$ and consider the splitting field of $\Phi_8(x)=x^4+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.
Its degree over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is given by the least $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$ such that $8\mid(p^k-1)$, i.e. $2$.
It follows that $\Phi_8$ factors over $\mathbb{F}_p$ as the product of two quadratic irreducible polynomials.
Let us denote through $i$ and $\sqrt{2}$ the elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ solving $x^2+1=0$ and $x^2-2=0$.
Let us consider the irreducible factor of $\Phi_8$ vanishing at $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$. By Frobenius automorphism, the conjugated root is $\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^p = \frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ where the last equality follows from $p\equiv 3\pmod{8}$.
Thus we have that one of the irreducible factors of $\Phi_8$ is 
$$ \left(x-\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(x-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=x^2-\sqrt{-2}\,x-1 $$
and since the coefficients of this polynomial belong to $\mathbb{F}_p$, $-2$ is a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{p}$.

$\frac{p-1}{2}$ being a prime is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

i wasn't going to post this but the other solution is so complicated i felt compelled to post it. (despite the fact that it is actually a much stronger solution)

My solution needs  $\frac{(p-1)}{2} $ to be prime to use the Legendre symbol's and the fact that $ 4= 2^2 $ is a obviously a quadratic residue.

$(\frac{(p-1)}{2}/p)=(2(p-1)/p) \equiv (\frac{-1}{p})(\frac{2}{p})  $

Since $p\equiv 3 \mod 8 $ we have $(\frac{2}{p}) =-1 $ by theorem.

Since $p\equiv 3 \mod 8 \to p\equiv 3 \mod 4 \to (\frac{-1}{p})=-1 \to (\frac{-1}{p})(\frac{2}{p})=(-1)(-1)=1 $

$\therefore (\frac{(p-1)}{2}/p)=1 $ thus $ \frac{(p-1)}{2} $ is a quadratic residue of p as desired.

Comment: Well, but if already know ("*by theorem*") which primes are such that $-1$ and/or $2$ are quadratic residues, your question is completely trivial by just invoking the multiplicativity of the Legendre symbol. I guessed you wanted to prove from scratch that $p\equiv 3\pmod{8}$ implies that $\frac{p-1}{2}$ (or $-2$, same thing) is a quadratic residue.

Comment: I quite like your solution actually i just thought the trivial solution may be helpful to some people so i posted it.